# How to create user for existing

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-agent

I have a database which get restored everyday through a agent job, but after restoration the user gets killed so i want to create a step so that after restoration user should be created with readonly permission.

`CREATE USER [username] FOR LOGIN [loginname]
 ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER []`

Is this ok ?

Answer (score 1):

*Is this ok ?*

The db_datareader role gives implicit access to SELECT against all tables and views in a database.

If **that's** ok, then **it's** ok

You might be interested in the information in [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1900/understanding-sql-server-fixed-database-roles/) post about db_datareader

You can conditionally check to see if the user already exists

```
use myDB
GO

if not exists(select * from sys.database_principals where name = 'foo')
-- create your database user
```

When restoring or attaching databases where the user already exists, you might have to 'remap' any Sql logins to the restored database.  This is what I use as part of normal 'refresh' scripts

```
use <YourDatabase>
go
set nocount on
declare @cmd varchar(max)=''
select
    @Cmd=@cmd + 'ALTER USER ' + dp.name + ' WITH LOGIN = ' + dp.name + ';' + char(10)
from
    sys.database_principals dp left join
    master.sys.server_principals sp on
        sp.name=dp.name
where
    dp.type='s' and
    dp.default_schema_name<>dp.name and
    sp.name is not null
exec (@cmd)
```

Comment: Do i need to mention 
' IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'user') '

Comment: Your initial question stated that the 'user' wasn't in the source database which is why you were creating the 'user' after the restore.  I've updated my answer to add some additional information regarding this.